# SQL: Find smallest positive time difference

Tags: sql, date, difference, closest

I have the following situation that I can't seem to solve.
I have a table with each valuation an ID received, ordered in time. Each ID can have multiple valuations but only one of those valuation will lead to a purchase, the last valuation. I want to calculate the time between the last offer date and the date the offer is accepted (purchase at date).

In some cases, the offer date is posterior to the purchase date (why this happens is not relevant).
In this cases, I need to go and find in the previous valuation, which one is the one that lead to the purchase. In other words, which valuation has a timestamp with a date prior to the purchase. Also, I would need to get the closest date that meets this criteria, since there can be other previous values that meet the criteria.

Here is an example:

| Offer date | Purchase date | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-12 14:23:08 | NULL | SP66HC |
| **2021-09-07 13:31:21** | NULL | SP66HC |
| 2021-09-07 14:14:09 | NULL | SP66HC |
| 2021-09-13 10:50:15 | **2021-09-07 13:36:53** | SP66HC |

In this example the difference in time should be about 5 minutes (purchase date - offer date), but we had to look for previous valuations. Also, it is important to add that this has to be partitioned by ID.

Any suggestions? I thought of a WHILE loop but can't seem to be working.

THANK YOU!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products have their own, non-ANSI SQL compliant, functions.)

Comment: The above "dates" are timestamps.

Comment: I would add a "unique" id so you can seperate each row more easily, and then take the difference in time between the two id's

Comment: So basically you want to match not null purchase dates with nearest row that has a null purchase date?

Comment: @jarlh, yes true sorry about that. I'm using generic SQL, according to DataGrip.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cross join approach:

```sql
SELECT ID, MIN(t1.purchase_date - t2.offer_date) AS min_time
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE
    t1.purchase_date > t2.offer_date
GROUP BY ID;
```

This pairs each offer date with each purchase date.  We then take the minimum time difference for each `ID`.

Note that finding the difference between two timestamps in some unit is highly database-specific.  As you did not give us an RDBMS, I have simply represented the difference using subtraction (which would actually work in some places).

Comment: I'd say _self_ join.